# Keyboard shortcut for "Remove everyone and end meeting"

Tags: autoit, lync

I want to end a group conversation in Microsoft Lync 2010 such that it deletes the people from the conversation and then terminates the Group Conversation.It can be done simply by clicking on People options in the window and then clicking on the "Remove everyone and end meeting button.But i want a Keyboard shortcut to do the same.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use the [AutoIt Window Information Tool](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/au3spy.htm) to find out the control handle and then you just write a script with an infinitive main loop `While True` with a `Sleep(60*1000)` in it, closing with `WEnd`. Before the loop, you should use `HotKeySet("{Ctrl}{Alt}x", "removeAndExit")` and the last thing you need is the `Function removeAndExit()` which is performing a `ControlClick($windowHandle, "", $controlHandle, "primary")` and finally the `EndFunc`.